# How to get addition of columns using pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

[image]

I am doing pivot of same using below query

```
SELECT * INTO #tempData
FROM (
    SELECT
      [Name]
      ,[Points]
      ,[Date]
  FROM [GraphData].[dbo].[dummytable]
) t
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Points)
    FOR [Date] in ([January 2020],[February 2020],[March 2020])
) as pivot_table
SELECT * FROM #tempData
```

using this I am getting result as below

[image]

But I want sum of all previous columns in next columns i.e. I am expecting result something like this

[image]

Here we can see that in feb 20 it is sum of jan20 + feb20 data & in march20 it will be sum of jan20+feb20+mar20 data. Like this I can have any number columns.

But somehow I am not able to achieve same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a running sum to your subquery, you can do this with window aggregate.

If you want to avoid nulls, you need to also start with a table of months as a driving row and left join your table. To create a month table, you can either use a table variable/TVP or use a tally table/function to create one on the fly (there are many examples of this online)

```sql
SELECT * INTO #tempData
FROM (
    SELECT
      Name
      ,Date = m.Month
      ,RunningSum = SUM(Points) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY m.Month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  FROM Months m
  LEFT JOIN GraphData.dbo.dummytable t ON t.Date = m.Month
) t
PIVOT
(
    SUM(RunningSum)
    FOR Date in ([January 2020],[February 2020],[March 2020])
) as pivot_table
```

This **only** works if your dates are actually stored in a `date/datetime` column, otherwise you will need to convert in the `ORDER BY` to get the sorting properly.

Comment: This does not work when we do not have data for that particular data. e.g. as I do not have data of P1 for Mar20, it is giving NULL but it should give 220

Comment: You need to join a calendar table, see edit

Answer (score -1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date in ('January 2020') THEN Points ELSE 0 END) as Jan_20,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date in ('January 2020', 'February 2020') THEN Points ELSE 0 END) as Feb_20,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date in ('January 2020', 'February 2020', 'Mar 2020') THEN Points ELSE 0 END) as Mar_20
INTO #tempData
FROM [GraphData].[dbo].[dummytable]
GROUP BY Name;
```

If your dates are actually stored as *dates*, then this is simpler:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date < '2020-02-01' THEN Points ELSE 0 END) as Jan_20,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date < '2020-03-01' THEN Points ELSE 0 END) as Feb_20,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date < '2020-04-01' THEN Points ELSE 0 END) as Mar_20
INTO #tempData
FROM [GraphData].[dbo].[dummytable]
WHERE date >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: I can have any number of months in my table

Comment: @vaibhavshah . . .  Did you downvote the answer?